# How to remove `group` column from magneto admin customer grid?

Tags: magento

I want to remove the column `Group` from Magento admin side. 
I tried with the following, but it didn't work:

```
$this->removeColumn('group');
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can see the below file:

`app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php`

It will be better if you will copy this file to your local folder so that on any Magento upgrades your customizations will not be undone.

```
app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php
```

In this you will see the below code:

```
  /*  $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
        ->load()
        ->toOptionHash();

    $this->addColumn('group', array(
        'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
        'width'     =>  '100',
        'index'     =>  'group_id',
        'type'      =>  'options',
        'options'   =>  $groups,
    ));
*/
```

Just comment out this code and you will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file path: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php

and add the following code to remove group column from Magento admin customer grid.

```
$this->addColumn('group', array(
    'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
    'width'     =>  '100',
    'index'     =>  'group_id',
    'type'      =>  'options',
    'options'   =>  $groups,
));
```